# How does the Javascript Thread know where in the context to return to?

Tags: javascript

So let's say we have some code like this:

```
const a = 2;
const b = 4;
const addFunc = (x, y) => x + y;
const c = addFunc(a, b);
// some more code
```

So the thread will store the global constants a and b in memory, store the function addFunc in memory and then store c and assign it the return value of `addFunc(a, b)`. The callstack at the point where the thread is inside the function will have global and `addFunc(2, 4`). When the thread finishes by returning the return value and popping the `addFunc(2, 4)` from the callstack, how does it know where in the global context in needs to go back to? (e.g don't go back to executing the line:)

```
const a = 2;
```

Comment: This [blog](https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c)  might help you.

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan It mentions that "Once all the code of the function is executed, JS engines pop’s out that function’s execution context and start’s executing the function which is below it.". So does this mean that once it finishes executing the function, it'll find the function that it executed and continue from there or is there some kind of reference to where the function that was executed was? I assumed the latter, but in that case, where is that reference stored?

Comment: If you have a file with `func1(); funct2(); func3()` it would execute 1 then when it finishes, it would execute 2, then 3. However, that doesn't mean that after executing `func1` from wherever it would return to a single place. If `func3` also calls `func1()` then JS will still go through `func1` again but it would return either back in `func3` if the call originates from there or back in that original fictional file I used as an example. It depends on where it started from.

Comment: The function is *executed* where the two `()` are. Where it has been declared doesn't matter.